# Rider/ReSharper - Wrap chained method calls before first method

Tags: resharper, jetbrains-ide, code-formatting, rider

I have set `Line Brakes and Wrapping -> Arrangement of Members Access Expression -> Wrap chained method calls` to `Chop always`
Rider is formatting chained method calls this was:

```csharp
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var odds = numbers.Where(number => number % 2 == 0)
    .Select(number => number + 1)
    .ToList();
```

Is there a way that Rider would format this by breaking before first method call, if there is more then one call in chain?

Expected result:

```csharp
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var odds = numbers
    .Where(number => number % 2 == 0)
    .Select(number => number + 1)
    .ToList();
```

Available options in Rider:

[image: Available options in Rider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the "Prefer to wrap before first method call" setting.

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option in Rider :/ 
And I have newest version (2023.1.3)
I attached image in post showing my current options

Comment: And I don't see that option in JetBrains documentation

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/EditorConfig_CSHARP_LineBreaksPageSchema.html#Arrangement_of_member_access_expressions

Only the ones I have in Rider

Comment: Ok, I can see it in preview version. Unlucky that this feature is not there yet, but lucky that will be soon I guess. Thank You!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the setting was only added in 2023.2.